# css constant display of vertical scrollbar without doubling

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I've been reading other questions and results found on google on the subject of how to keep the `overflow-y scrollbar` constantly visible, to prevent any awkward transitions from page to page, if one page is long, and one page is short.

The following solution was suggested in most answers:

```
html {
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This does make the scrollbar visible on short pages that wouldn't normally have them, but on long pages that would, it's creating two scrollbars. One that is scrollable, and a grayed one that isn't.

[image]

I suppose this solution may have worked in the past, and it could be new browser versions treating it differently.

Is there any current way to have one single vertical scrollbar present on all pages regardless of whether it's scrollable?

```
body {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.5;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

to this

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Or just remove overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;

Comment: That's what I'm saying I did. I tried each of them individually. And just overflow-y: scroll; did not work.

Comment: Then somethin other is odd. The id assume you have a Wrapper around your content inside the body-tag, that tag has height 100% and overflow:auto; or something similar. can you post your whole css and html here or the live site?

Comment: I don't have anything like that on the wrapper, but I just tried fiddling with the body css. I removed overflow: auto; and that appeared to fix it, however, I didn't check in detail enough to see if there were any other side effects. I know there was a reason I added it, just can't quite recall. I added the css to the question.

Comment: There you have your height 100%, this must be removed along with the overflow:auto ;) that is what i ment with 'something similar'